# For each string in Array

Tags: arrays, string, unity-game-engine, unityscript

Just as the name says, I want that for each certain name in an array a value is added to a int.

For example: if there are 3 strings of the same name in the array, then 3 times 50 will be added to the value.

This is my script I have now:

```c#
var lootList = new Array();
var interaction : Texture;
var interact = false;
var position : Rect;
var ching : AudioClip;
var lootPrice = 0;

function Update()
{
    print(lootList);

    if ("chalice" in lootList){
        lootPrice += 50;
    }
}

function Start()
{
    position = Rect( ( Screen.width - interaction.width ) /2, ( Screen.height - interaction.height ) /2, interaction.width, interaction.height );
}

function OnTriggerStay(col : Collider)
{   
    if(col.gameObject.tag == "loot")
    {
        interact = true;

        if(Input.GetKeyDown("e"))
        {
            if(col.gameObject.name == "chalice")
            {
                Destroy(col.gameObject);
                print("chaliceObtained");
                audio.clip = ching;
                audio.pitch = Random.Range(0.8,1.2);
                audio.Play();
                interact = false;
                lootList.Add("chalice");
            }

            if(col.gameObject.name == "moneyPouch")
            {
                Destroy(col.gameObject);
                print("moneyPouchObtained");
                audio.clip = ching;
                audio.pitch = Random.Range(0.8,1.2);
                audio.Play();
                interact = false;
                lootList.Add("moneyPouch");
            }

            if(col.gameObject.name == "ring")
            {
                Destroy(col.gameObject);
                print("ringObtained");
                audio.clip = ching;
                audio.pitch = Random.Range(0.8,1.2);
                audio.Play();
                interact = false;
                lootList.Add("ring");
            }

            if(col.gameObject.name == "goldCoins")
            {
                Destroy(col.gameObject);
                print("coldCoinsObtained");
                audio.clip = ching;
                audio.pitch = Random.Range(0.8,1.2);
                audio.Play();
                interact = false;
                lootList.Add("goldCoins");
            }

            if(col.gameObject.name == "plate")
            {
                Destroy(col.gameObject);
                print("plateObtained");
                audio.clip = ching;
                audio.pitch = Random.Range(0.8,1.2);
                audio.Play();
                interact = false;
                lootList.Add("plate");
            }
        }
    }
}

function OnTriggerExit(col : Collider)
{   
    if(col.gameObject.tag == "pouch")
    {
        interact = false;
    }
}

function OnGUI()
{
    if(interact == true)
    {
        GUI.DrawTexture(position, interaction);
        GUI.color.a = 1;
    }
}
```

It's for a game I'm making where you can steal items for extra score points.

I've tried using the `for(i = 0; i < variable.Length; i++)` but that didn't seem to work.

The only thing I can think of now is using booleans to add it once. But that isn't memory friendly.

Help is appreciated and thanks in advance!

Comment: And where should the loop be? We don't know how your script is supposed to work. Is all the code necessary for the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the standard `.forEach(callback)` method:

```c#
lootList.forEach(function(value, index, array)
{
    if (value === "chalice") { lootPrice += 50; }
});
```

If you don't have that method, you could implement it like this:

```c#
if (!Array.prototype.forEach) {
    Array.prototype.forEach = function (callback) {
        for(var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) { callback(this[i], i, this); }
    }
}
```